# How to fix all the errors and successfully run the Akka Distributed Workers Sample Project?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I am trying to run the Akka Distributed Workers project following the guide here https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-distributed-workers-scala/

On run, it fails with series of error messages. The first one that caught my attention was:

```
14:42:36.747 [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] ERROR akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider - No root guardian at [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2554]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong protocol of [akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2554/], expected [akka]
```

Indeed when I take a look at the configuration `"akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2554"` is used.

But why is the sample with the wrong format? Maybe the format changed?

Anyways I changed to `"akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2554"` then attempted to run again...

The error about wrong protocol seems to be gone, but now I got the following error:

> [error] (run-main-1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected
>   possible incompatible versions on the classpath. Please note that a
>   given Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that
>   you are using, e.g. if you use [2.6.0] all other modules that are
>   released together MUST be of the same version. Make sure you're using
>   a compatible set of libraries. Possibly conflicting versions [2.6.0,
>   2.5.23] in libraries [akka-persistence:2.6.0, akka-persistence-query:2.5.23, akka-coordination:2.6.0,
>   akka-actor:2.6.0, akka-slf4j:2.6.0, akka-remote:2.6.0,
>   akka-cluster:2.6.0, akka-protobuf-v3:2.6.0, akka-stream:2.6.0,
>   akka-cluster-tools:2.6.0]

Which is also strange as I did not modify any of the dependencies...why does the sample project ship with incompatible versions for dependencies?

Anyways I noticed `akka-persistence-query:2.5.23` is the offending one. it is version 2.5.23 instead of 2.6.0 like everyone else.

But there is no where `akka-persistence-query` is explicitly added. How then to correct the version?

Then the finally set of errors has to do with binding to ports:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on 127.0.0.1.
        at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Server.start(Server.java:160) ~[cassandra-bundle.jar:0.100-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.util.Collections$SingletonSet.forEach(Collections.java:4767) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Not quite sure why this is error is occurring. Is it related to the prior version issue?

Well, I would appreciate insights from anyone more knowledeable than myself:

1. Is changing the protocol URL actually the right thing to do?
2. How to resolve the version incompatibility error?
3. How to resolve the port error?

Comment: I've logged an issue on github: https://github.com/akka/akka-distributed-workers-scala.g8/issues/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after discussion with someone from Lightbend on the Gitter, It was discovered that the sample was temporary broken, and the upgrade to version 2.6.0 should not have been the case.

I modified the version to 2.5.26 and everything works fine.

An issue was opened to fix this here https://github.com/akka/akka-distributed-workers-scala.g8/issues/17